# ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:43:42

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-redux

I installed `react-router-dom` to my typescript `react-redux` website and now I get the error in the title, my `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "typescript-webpack-react-flux-boilerplate",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "license": "MIT",
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+https://github.com/pepaar/typescript-webpack-react-flux-boilerplate.git"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node server.js",
        "build": "webpack"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/react": "15.0.28",
        "@types/react-dom": "15.5.0",
        "@types/react-redux": "4.4.38",
        "@types/react-router": "^4.0.18",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
        "@types/react-router-redux": "^5.0.10",
        "@types/redux-actions": "1.2.6",
        "@types/redux-logger": "3.0.0",
        "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
        "material-ui": "^0.19.4",
        "react": "15.6.0",
        "react-dom": "15.6.0",
        "react-redux": "5.0.5",
        "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
        "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
        "redux": "3.6.0",
        "redux-actions": "2.0.3",
        "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
        "redux-thunk": "2.2.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.1.3",
        "babel-cli": "6.24.1",
        "babel-core": "6.25.0",
        "babel-loader": "7.0.0",
        "babel-plugin-external-helpers": "6.22.0",
        "babel-polyfill": "6.23.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-es2015-loose": "8.0.0",
        "css-loader": "0.28.4",
        "file-loader": "0.11.2",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "2.28.0",
        "less": "2.7.2",
        "less-loader": "4.0.4",
        "node-libs-browser": "2.0.0",
        "react-hot-loader": "1.3.1",
        "style-loader": "0.18.2",
        "tslint": "4.5.1",
        "tslint-loader": "3.5.3",
        "typescript": "2.3.4",
        "webpack": "2.6.1",
        "webpack-config": "7.0.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "2.4.5"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full error as it appears in the console, please?